# Having trouble using the java "if" statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to teach myself java by writing a simple weekly planner program and the if statment in my code is giving me grief, here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Week
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
   Scanner inorout = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Do you want to read or write (r/w)");
   String decision = inorout.nextLine();
   System.out.println(decision);
   if(decision == "r")
   {
     System.out.println("It has gone into the if");
     Scanner namer = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("What is the name of the week you want to read?");
     String r = namer.nextLine();
     Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(r + ".txt"));
     System.out.println("What is Your Name?");
     String name = s.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Welcome " + name);
   }    
 }
}
```

When I compile the program using Drjava and input "r" it doesn't run the if statment, and i'm at a loss as to whats wrong, help would be much appriciated

Comment: Please format the code using the code tag.

Comment: @Jarred looking at your comment `as in if(decision equals "r") ` it seems you do not have even basic understanding of Java syntax. -1

Answer (score 8):

Strings in Java are compared usually with `equals` not with `==`.

Comment: Not usually.  Always.  If you use `==` you're not comparing a String, you're comparing its pointer.

Comment: as in if(decision equals "r") ? because thats throwing up errors =/

Comment: @aroth: Thats not completely true. Strings are also immutable so if two strings have the same reference they will have also the same Object value. But i said usually because in 95% you will compare the values of strings with equals.

Comment: @aroth: in extremely unusual situations, you could use `intern()` to ensure that object equality is equivalent to reference equality, slightly improving the comparison speed.  This is almost never a useful thing to do, but it's worth being aware of.

Answer (score 3):

The `String decision` will not have reference-equality with the literal `"r"`. You need to use `String.equals` method.

Comment: Also note that a good habit to get into is to write code like `"r".equals(decision)` instead of `decision.equals("r")`.  The former will never throw a `NullPointerException`, the latter might.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `decision.equals("r")`.

`==` check for equality of the references to the objects, not for equality of the objects themselves.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you need to use `if(decision.equals("r"))` instead of `if(decision == "r")`.

Here's a brief explanation on how string references work in Java:

The `String` class keeps a pool of strings that are currently in use, and if a literal `"r"` was assigned to `decision`, or `decision` was internalized (put into the string pool) using `.intern()`, it will fetch it from the string pool and the references will be equal. But because `decision` is set at runtime using user input, it will not be internalized automatically, and the references will not be equal.

In short, in some situations `decision == "r"` can evaluate to `true`. But don't rely on it. Use `.equals()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(decision == "r")
```

== checks for object equality, *not* string equality
you instead need to use the equals() method

```
if(decision.equals("r"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like:

```
if(decision.equals("r"))
```

Comment: cheers to all who preovided answers, this solved the problem =)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point out that while the `decision.equals("r")` suggested in many answers will work just fine, it is equally valid to say:

```
if ("r".equals(decision)) {
   //do something...
}
```

The benefit of this is that you don't have to worry about `"r"` ever being `null`.  Also note that you may want to do a case-insensitive comparison in this case (so the user can type 'R' if they want), like:

```
if ("r".equalsIgnoreCase(decision)) {
   //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the equals method to compare the two strings,the string is a object,this is a reference,the equals() method will compare the content of two strings,but the == will compare the address of two strings

so,you should write like this:

```
if ("r".equals(decision)) {
//do something code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Equality vs. Identity

You check for **identical references** (`==`), or **equal objects** (`.equals()`).

Primitive data types (Int, Float, etc.) and references are compaired with `==`, complex data types (any normal or self-defined class, String, any object intantiatable by hand via `new`) have to be compaired by object1`.equals(`object2`)`.

Strings for example can return false positives for `==`, as can be seen in this runnable example here: (copy&paste into File `StringComparisonMain.java`, compile, run)

```
/**
 * Difference between identity and equality in java.
 */
public class StringComparisonMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * 
         * CREATE TWO DIFFERENT REFERENCES TO TWO DIFFERENT BUT EQUAL STRING
         * OBJECTS
         * 
         * 'two' must be created like this else test will create false
         * positives: one = "asdf"; two = "asdf"; ... will falsely yield 'true'
         * for identity check. This is due to optimizations going in inside the
         * JRE, I believe.
         */
        String one = "bla";
        String two;
        two = "b" + "l";
        two = two + "a";
        String three = "bla";

        /*
         * ACTUAL TESTING CODE
         */
        System.out.println("different reference leading to equal objects:");
        stringCompare(one, two);
        System.out.println("as above, but false positive: (!)");
        stringCompare(one, three);

        // changing to same references to the same String object
        one = two;

        System.out.println("identical references to same single object:");
        stringCompare(one, two);

        // different Strings (and ofc different objects...)
        one = "test";

        System.out.println("different Strings/objects:");
        stringCompare(one, two);

        System.out.println("\nDONE!");

    }

    private static void stringCompare(String stringOne, String stringTwo) {

        // first test for identity (reference to same object)
        if (stringOne == stringTwo) {
            System.out.println("== true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("== false");
        }

        // second test for equality (two referenced objects are equal)
        if (stringOne.equals(stringTwo)) {
            System.out.println("equals true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("equals false");
        }

        // there is not just 'System.out.println' out there...
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```